# Java JSP code not incrementing when I try to use it in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I am trying to allow the user to add rows to a table. When the user does this, I need to add a unique ID which I am trying to get by adding a number at the end of the ID each time the user adds a row.

I am trying to keep a count in `Java JSP` code and use it in a `JavaScript function` but it does not work. I have attached the code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <% int count=0; %>
    $("#addRow").click(function () {
                    <% count++; %>
                $("#firstRow").after('<tr><th scope="row"><%=count%></th> A BUNCH OF OTHER TABLE CODE GOES HERE BUT YOU GET THE POINT...
```

I keep getting the count to be = 1 each time. It only seems to increment the first time and never again.

Comment: Just use a pure Javascript solution

Comment: `<% xxx %>` code blocks **run on the server**. Since there is no loop in the code running on the server, `<%count++;%>` is executed exactly **once**. --- Also, your `<% xxx %>` code blocks don't generate any output, and `<%=count%>` generates the value `1`, so your client sees, e.g. `...<th scope="row">1</th>... --- Do a "View Source" in the web browser to see what the server has generated.

Comment: @ScaryWombat How do I put a JavaScript variable inside of that HTML? I don't have much experience with JavaScript and I can't figure it out

Comment: @Andreas I assumed it would get executed multiple times since the count++ is inside the onclick function but I guess it can only ever be called the first time you click it? So the only way to do this is with JavaScript since I can't use a loop because the user can add / remove rows whenever they want

Comment: @Sean17 You're totally missing the entire issue. The `<% xxx %>` blocks are **executed on the server** to generate the HTML to send to the browser. `click` is **execute on the client** *after* the server is **done**. Nothing you do on the client will make the server do anything, unless you're using AJAX, and you're definitely not. --- Let me repeat my earlier suggestion: Do a "**View Source**" in the web browser to see what the server has generated. Once you see that, you might better grasp the issue.

Comment: upon loading (as per normal JSP) store the value as a HTML hidden text value with an `id` - use JS or jquery to get that value and update it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I was able to fix the problem by using a JavaScript variable instead and then putting + count + inside of the HTML in the onclick. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Andreas Yes you are right. I did not realise that the server code could not be changed by client actions. Thanks for clearing that up for me. I fixed the issue by using a javascript variable instead and it seems to work. When I inspected element it updated correctly as well. Thanks for your answers and teaching me about how exactly the server side code worked!